# How to get header of the columns using Tabula-py

Tags: python, header, tabula

I am trying to fetch tables from my pdf using tabula-py. The tables in the pdf are without gridlines. when I am trying to fetch the table, the header is missing. For example, I have a pdf as below. My code is fetching from 
Physicians and Dentists     340.2   350.3   365.8   359.4, I need the header 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017 as well.

```
df = read_pdf('Denver.pdf', pages = 4, output_format= 'Csv',encoding='latin-1',pandas_options={'header': None})
```

[screenshot of the pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vW1p.png)

Comment: i think `pandas_options={'header': None}` is the problem

Comment: If I remove it, I am getting the first line as header. i.e. this is Physicians and Dentists 340.2 350.3 365.8 359.4 as header

Comment: Please upload your pdf file on drive and provide the link here. We can't do anything without the pdf